# How do the predict() and predict_proba() for xgbClassifier() work?

Tags: python, xgboost, xgboost-classifier, xgboost-predict

I am using xgboost classifier for a binary classification problem. I used the predict() to get the class predictions (0/1) but I also used the predict_proba() method to get the class probabilities (my intention for doing so is to play around with the probability-threshold  a bit). However, when I examined the false positives (and false negatives) and their corresponding predict_proba() outputs, I noticed that in many cases, even though probability for `class 0` is `**higher than 0.5**`, the predict() outputs a `class 1` (and similarly for false negatives). I am confused. I thought predict() methods utilizes a default threshold of 0.5 to put the datapoint in class 0 or 1. Here is an example:

```
                        0         1
2022-04-02 06:58  0.647819  0.352181
2023-02-10 22:12  0.717162  0.282838
2023-02-10 15:18  0.692320  0.307680
```

while the `predict()` outputted `class 1`.

Can someone explain this apparent discrepancy in the output (OR it could be my misunderstanding of how predict() works)?

Thanks.